# ¿Como hago para redireccionar a una pagina automaticamente después de cierto tiempo de inactividad

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

Quiero que después de cierto tiempo en el cual no se haya hecho ningún clic, o actividad en la pagina, esta se redireccione a otra pagina la cual seria la de inicio de sesion

Comment: Cuando estás construyendo una aplicación de angular por lo general es una mala idea mezclar código de este con código de jquery en lugares que no sean directivas o providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción con JavaScript (sin necesidad de frameworks o bibliotecas) sería programar la redirección cuando se cargue la página y reiniciarla cada vez que se hiciera click en algún lugar del documento. Algo como esto:

```
// función encargada de la redirección
function redireccion() {
    window.location = "http://mipagina.com/pagina-de-inicio-sesion";
}

// se llamará a la función que redirecciona después de 10 minutos (600.000 segundos)
var temp = setTimeout(redireccion, 600000);

// cuando se pulse en cualquier parte del documento
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // borrar el temporizador que redireccionaba
    clearTimeout(temp);
    // y volver a iniciarlo
    temp = setTimeout(redireccion, 600000);
})
```

Pero ojo, realmente esto sólo controlaría la inactividad en el lado del cliente. Sería mejor un método que controlara la inactividad tanto en el lado del cliente como del servidor (un usuario con conocimientos de JavaScript podría deshabilitar esta redirección y tener una sesión ilimitada si no se controla nada en el lado del servidor).

Comment: tu respuesta me sirvió, pero pasa que no es necesario el control por el lado del servidor en este caso

Comment: Personalmente el evento que utilizaría sería `mousemove` en lugar del `click` ya que el usuario podría estar interactuando con elementos de la aplicación sin necesidad de hacer `click`, por ejemplo con menús contextuales que se despliegan al `mouseover` o elementos similares a tooltips, etc. Por otro lado y por afinar un poco más seria bueno comprobar que tampoco está interactuando con el teclado o cualquier otro periférico.

Comment: @eledgaar acabo de cambiar el evento como dijiste, me parece mejor, pero no veo necesario eso de comprobar si esta  interactuando con otros periféricos, la verdad quería algo simple, sin usar bibliotecas o un código largo, el código de arriba mas tu recomendacion me sirve bastante. el tema esta en que puse el temporizador a media hora y no creo que ningún usuario se quede mirando la pantalla sin mover el mouse por media hora, mas para la aplicación que estoy ayudando a desarrollar, esta funcion es mas para que no se quede abierto la sesión si se deja abierta.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias evaluar usar una libreria como ser

[Ng-Idle](http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/)

veo bastante simple de utilizar, basicamente defines el js

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-idle.min.js"></script>
```

lo configuras en el modulo

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngIdle']);
```

en el controller podrias atrapar los eventos

```
 $scope.$on('IdleStart', function() { ..

 $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {...

 $scope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {...
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta cuando se está usando angular.